# Textbox show previous date when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, calendar

I have a `textbox` for date, which is selected from `calendar control`.

So what happening here is,

*Whenever I select a date from the calendar, and go and change the date inside the textbox.*

After button click what happening here is, *the textbox again goes back to the date which was selected from the calendar.*

I dont know why.

Below is my aspx:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpCal" autocomplete="off" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server"
                        MaxLength="20" Width="70" Style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: bottom right;
                        border: solid 1px #ACACAC" onblur="funfillcalBook(this)"></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:Calendar AutoPostBack="false" ID="CalEntryDt1" runat="server" DatePickerMode="true"
                        TextBoxId="txtExpCal" DatePickerImagePath="../Images/icon2.gif" CultureName="en-GB">
                    </cc1:Calendar>
```

I also tried like below, but it didn't worked.

```
function funfillcalBook(obj) {
        var strcon = (dateformat(obj.value, ''));
        if (obj.value != "") {
            if (typeof (strcon) == "undefined") {
                from = obj.value.split("/");
                strdt = from[1].toString() + "/" + from[0].toString() + "/" + from[2].toString()
                CalEntryDt1.setDate(new Date(strdt), new Date(strdt))
            }
            else if (document.getElementById(obj.id).value != "" && strcon == false) {
                document.getElementById(obj.id).focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess your button click causing postback which is resetting default date

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje: Yes, the textbox is getting `postback`..!

Comment: Have you solved it already? great!

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje: **No**, when did I say that ?

Comment: put your textbox inside ajax update panel control, and try

Comment: I tried, but its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97408/discussion-between-vijay-kumbhoje-and-coder).